# How to get month name from ISO date using moment js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, highcharts, momentjs

I am trying to extract the month name from ISO dates.

I am trying this:

`moment('2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]').month('MMMM');`

I am getting `invalid date`.

How can I extract the month name and the week number from ISO dates?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. You should do this instead though: `.format('MMMM');`

Comment: [*month*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/) gets or sets the day of the month. If you provide a value, it sets the month. Use [*format*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/).

Comment: @mechanical_meat, if you submit this as an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @noob: ok, I will. Thanks.

Comment: @noob—do you want the local month or UTC month? If you're west of Greenwich, 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z may return December. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, use `.format()` instead:

```
moment('2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]').format('MMMM');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `format()` method.
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/

```
var month = moment('2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]').format('MMMM');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already an answer for doing this with moment.js, so for completeness here's one for using *toLocaleString*. Note that the input string needs to be compliant with the [format specified by ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-date-time-string-format).

One issue to consider is whether you want the UTC month or user's local month. For users with a negative timezone offset, '2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z' is in December, not January, e.g.:

```js
let d = new Date('2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z');
// Zero offset
let utcMonth = d.toLocaleString('en',{month:'long', timeZone:'UTC', timeZoneName: 'long'});
// Negative offset
let spMonth = d.toLocaleString('en',{month:'long', timeZone:'America/Sao_Paulo', timeZoneName: 'long'}); 
console.log('The UTC month is  : ' + utcMonth + '\nSao Paulo month is: ' + spMonth);
```

By specifying the timezone as UTC, it ensures that users with a negative timezone offset get January, not their local month which will be December.